# DataBinding ListView creating components if a certain condition is met

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am working on a C# WPF project and I have a list view which uses data binding and a collection view.

Below is how my ListView is currently populated.

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="547,12,0,41" Name="lstCallLogInformation" Width="320">
            <ListView.Style>
                <Style TargetType="ListView">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                                        <TextBlock Text="No items in your devices call log" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Style>
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray" Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </Expander.Header>
                                            <ItemsPresenter />
                                        </Expander>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Control.HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel Style="{StaticResource onmouseover}">
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal" Tag="{Binding logID}">
                            <Image Height="30" Source="{Binding base64ImageString, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}" Width="30" />
                            <StackPanel Margin="10" Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding contactNameOrPhoneNumber}" />
                                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding dateString}" />
                                    <TextBlock Margin="15, 0, 0, 0" Text="Duration: " />
                                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding humanReadableCallDuration}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Button Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" Tag="{Binding logID}" Name="btnAddAsContact" Click="btnAddAsContact_Click">
                                    <Image Width="15" Height="15" Source="/BoardiesSMSServer;component/images/add.png" Tag="{Binding logID}" />
                                </Button>
                                <Button Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" Tag="{Binding logID}" Name="btnDeleteContactFromLog" Click="btnDeleteContactFromLog_Click">
                                    <Image Width="15" Height="15" Source="/BoardiesSMSServer;component/images/delete.png" Margin="0,0,0,5" Tag="{Binding logID}"  />
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Within my DockPanel within the DataTemplate I have a StackPanel which contains various TextBlocks from the array that is passed into the binding.

In one of the StackPanels you will see you will see a TextBlock that binds to the element of `contactNameOrPhoneNumber`.

What I want to be able to do is if another value from the binding is null then I add a TextBlock for the `` contactNameOrPhoneNumber` element and alongside it have another TextBlock which contains another element of `` number``, if the other binding value is not null then this extra textblock of number is not added.

So in simple terms, what I want to be able to do is within the DataTemplate have a conditional if statement of if binding value == null add textblock to stackpanel else don't add textblock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with **`Style + Triggers`** something like this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PropertyName}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

---

Also you can create [**IValueConverter**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) say **`ObjectToVisibilityConverter`** which will take input your property and if property is null return **`Visibility.Collapsed`** else return **`Visibility.Visible`**.

You can then bind property with Visibility value of TextBlock via Converter.

```
<TextBlock Visibility="{Binding PropertyName,
                       Converter={StaticResource ObjectToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```